# Display data in a listView which is returned from a webservice in form of xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Guys am abit new to android but i have developed an android application that connects to the webservice and returns an xml file...problem is i have failed to find a way of displaying this data in a list view. Please guys help and tell me how am going wrong

```
 package com.example.testservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Statement extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button BtnBack, BtnSend;
    String AccountNumer, xmlreturn;
    EditText _AccountNumer;
    TextView trandate, tranType, amount;
    Context context;
//private ListView lv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statement);

        //trandate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //tranType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        //amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        BtnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        BtnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        _AccountNumer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        // lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        BtnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        BtnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AccountNumer = _AccountNumer.getText().toString();
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();

            }
        });
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            xmlreturn = WebService.StateMentWS(AccountNumer, "getStateMent");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlreturn));
                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("statementTable");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    Element providerID = (Element) node;
                    NodeList providerIDlist = providerID.getElementsByTagName("trandate");
                    Element providerIDelement = (Element) providerIDlist.item(0);
                    providerIDlist = providerIDelement.getChildNodes();
                    String MProviderIDL = providerIDlist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    listdata.add(MProviderIDL);

                    Element providerName = (Element) node;
                    NodeList providerNamelist = providerName.getElementsByTagName("tran_type");
                    Element prividerNameElement = (Element) providerNamelist.item(0);
                    providerNamelist = prividerNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    AdvImglist.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    String MProviderNameL = providerNamelist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    MProviderNameL.toString());
                    listdata.add(MProviderNameL);

                    Element providerNamet = (Element) node;
                    NodeList providerNamelistt = providerNamet.getElementsByTagName("tran_type");
                    Element prividerNameElementt = (Element) providerNamelistt.item(0);
                    providerNamelist = prividerNameElementt.getChildNodes();
                    AdvImglist.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    MProviderNameL = providerNamelist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    MProviderNameL.toString());
                    listdata.add(MProviderNameL);
                    Element providerNametx = (Element) node;
                    NodeList providerNamets = providerNametx.getElementsByTagName("amount");
                    Element prividerNameElementtttx = (Element) providerNamets.item(0);
                    providerNamelist = prividerNameElementtttx.getChildNodes();
                    AdvImglist.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    MProviderNameL = providerNamelist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    MProviderNameL.toString());
                    listdata.add(MProviderNameL);
                }

                ListView ListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                (context, android.R.layout.
                                        simple_list_item_1, listdata);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource
                        (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                ListView1.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.statement, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

when i click the button i get an exception that the application stopped working but i don't get anything logged in the logcat.

Comment: try filter logcat to check error:

`adb logcat *:E`

Comment: If your app is crashed, then there should be an exception log..